# jQuery increment number id conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have my markup like this

```
<table>
<tr class="resource-data">
    <td>
        <select name="resource[product-name][0]" class="resource-product-name resource" data-name="resource[product_name]">
            <option value="apple" data-id="apple">Apple</option>
            <option value="bus" data-id="bus">Bus</option>
            <option value="car" data-id="car">Car</option>
            <option value="duster" data-id="duster">Duster</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" class="product-type" name="resource[product_type][0]" 
            data-name="resource[product_type]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="product-class" name="resource[product_class][0]" 
            data-name="resource[product_class]"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right add-new-data"> Add </button>
```

here you can see I have used array with 0 in the names for the attributes. Now when I am getting the data from table with the increment order my markup goes like this

**Html Code**

```
<table>
<tr class="resource-data">
    <td>
        <select name="resource[product-name][0]" class="resource-product-name resource" data-name="resource[product_name]">
            <option value="apple" data-id="apple">Apple</option>
            <option value="bus" data-id="bus">Bus</option>
            <option value="car" data-id="car">Car</option>
            <option value="duster" data-id="duster">Duster</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" class="product-type" name="resource[product_type][0]" 
        data-name="resource[product_type]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="product-class" name="resource[product_class][0]" 
            data-name="resource[product_class]"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="resource-data">
    <td>
        <select name="resource[product-name][1]" class="resource-product-name resource" data-name="resource[product_name]">
            <option value="apple" data-id="apple">Apple</option>
            <option value="bus" data-id="bus">Bus</option>
            <option value="car" data-id="car">Car</option>
            <option value="duster" data-id="duster">Duster</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" class="product-type" name="resource[product_type][1]" 
        data-name="resource[product_type]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="product-class" name="resource[product_class][1]" 
            data-name="resource[product_class]"></td>
</tr>       
</table>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right add-new-data"> Add </button>
```

Now when I am using js to add another row with the increment number with this code

**JS Code**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var Clone = jQuery('table tr.resource-data:first').clone();
        jQuery('body').on('click','button.add-new-data', function() {
            var GetRows = $("table tr.resource-data").length;
            var ParentRow = $("table tr.resource-data").last();
            Clone.clone(true).insertAfter(ParentRow);
            ParentRow.find("select.resource").each(function() {
                var currentName = $(this).attr("data-name");
                $(this).attr("name", currentName + "["+GetRows+"]");
            });
            ParentRow.find("input.product-type").each(function() {
                var currentName = $(this).attr("data-name");
                $(this).attr("name", currentName + "["+GetRows+"]");
            });
            ParentRow.find("input.product-class").each(function() {
                var currentName = $(this).attr("data-name");
                $(this).attr("name", currentName + "["+GetRows+"]");
            });                         
        });
    });
```

It is doing the increment number 0 two times. Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NewUserFiddle/5mp7hnsp/). So can someone tell me how to fix this. Any help and suggestions will be really apreciable. Thanks

Comment: Check this solution **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5mp7hnsp/2/)** Updated the row count logic. You need to modify the newly added row, so *ParentRow* should be assigned newly added row's jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

Check it out here http://jsfiddle.net/5mp7hnsp/1/

You were cloning the first element and using it every time you click on the add button.

That's why the newly added row ended up having index zero.

Although you tried to change its attributes of the children after the insertion, it was meaningless because you selected the target element, not the added element which you're supposed to manipulate afterward.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var Clone = jQuery('table tr.resource-data:first').clone();
    jQuery('body').on('click','button.add-new-data', function() {
        var GetRows = $("table tr.resource-data").length;
        var ParentRow = $("table tr.resource-data").last();
        Clone.clone(true).insertAfter(ParentRow);
        var newRow = $("table tr.resource-data").last();
        newRow.find("select.resource").each(function() {
            var currentName = $(this).attr("data-name");
            $(this).attr("name", currentName + "["+GetRows+"]");
        });
        newRow.find("input.product-type").each(function() {
            var currentName = $(this).attr("data-name");
            $(this).attr("name", currentName + "["+GetRows+"]");
        });
        newRow.find("input.product-class").each(function() {
            var currentName = $(this).attr("data-name");
            $(this).attr("name", currentName + "["+GetRows+"]");
        });                         
    });
});
```